# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to write a python script which logs into Kahoot with multiple accounts. I ran into the following problem: I tried to locate the 'Enter' button with Selenium and click it. But I got this message: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".enter-button__EnterButton-sc-1o9b9va-0 gSoXKU"} (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)`
I have no clue why it does not work. Here is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

class kahoot_tab:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\...\chromedriver.exe')
        self.driver.get('https://kahoot.it/')

    def enter_pin(self, pin):
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('gameId').send_keys(pin)
        self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('enter-button__EnterButton-sc-1o9b9va-0 gSoXKU').click()

tab1 = kahoot_tab()
tab1.enter_pin('123456')
```

The thing that makes me frustrated is that this element exists as this is the HTML code: `<button type="submit" value="Submit" class="enter-button__EnterButton-sc-1o9b9va-0 gSoXKU" data-functional-selector="join-game-pin"><span>Enter</span></button>`

Please help me!

P.S.: I also tried it with `time.sleep(100)` between sending the pin and clicking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target element having more than one class name.

i.e *`enter-button__EnterButton-sc-1o9b9va-0`* and *`gSoXKU`*

You can't achieve using **`.find_element_by_class_name`**, because this method just for single class name.

Instead, for multiple class names, you can use **`.find_element_by_css_selector`** with this value *`.enter-button__EnterButton-sc-1o9b9va-0.gSoXKU`*:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.enter-button__EnterButton-sc-1o9b9va-0.gSoXKU').click()
```

[CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: @MichaelHofmann welcome, glad to hear it worked. See the above updated answer with more explanation, hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the full XPath of the enter button instead of selecting it with its class name. Having that said, your code should be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

class kahoot_tab:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\...\chromedriver.exe')
        self.driver.get('https://kahoot.it/')

    def enter_pin(self, pin):
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('gameId').send_keys(pin)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div/main/div/form/button').click()

tab1 = kahoot_tab()
tab1.enter_pin('123456')
```

Also another thing is the use WebDriverWait. For example:

```
enter_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div/div/main/div/form/button")))
```

By using this, you are waiting for the element to fully load before pressing it.

Comment: Also thanks to you, but since I don't really know how x paths work i prefer @FrianH s method.

Comment: You are very welcome! I prefer using XPath since the id or class of the element has a bigger chance to change in the future... well, at least in some of the webpages I have tested in the past. The accepted answer still is a great way to do it, I'm used to XPath and that's what I've been using without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative that doesn't rely on the element's classes or full XPATH

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
...
enter_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(span, 'Enter')]")
enter_button.click()
```

You should utilise Selenium's [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to ensure that the `gameId` is visible before trying to `send_keys()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think @frianH s answer is simpler.

Comment: That's fine, the accepted answer is whatever helped you the most :). I offered this as an answer because it avoids using the classes which look like they're CSS modules and might change in the future.